# unable to live site in server laravel5

Tags: php, laravel-5, cpanel

iam getting an error after uploaded project to server. when i visited to link `somedomain.com/DEMO` i got following error. What actually is this error? how can i solve it please help me.

```
Warning: require(/home/siddins/public_html/DEMO/project/app/http/helpers/backend/helpers.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/siddins/public_html/DEMO/project/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 54

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/siddins/public_html/DEMO/project/app/http/helpers/backend/helpers.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/siddins/public_html/DEMO/project/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 54
```

my index.php is like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylorotwell@gmail.com>
 */

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels nice to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/project/bootstrap/autoload.php';



/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/project/bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel');

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

project is main folder . Inside projetc i have `app,vendor,bootstrap,config,database,resources` etc

Comment: Have you rename or move your `/public` folder??

Comment: i have rename /public folder

Comment: Please project your sample project structure.

Comment: Try this url : `somedomain.com/DEMO/project/public`

Comment: structure is like this  project/app/Http/Helpers/backend/helpers.php

Comment: i have like this  DEMO/project/app/Http/Helpers/backend/helpers.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90199/discussion-between-indrasinh-bihola-and-ranjeet-karki).

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of the best practices while launching a Laravel app on server.
Try them out. Might solve your issues. These steps have solved almost every problem that I have faced till now while launching a site on server.

1.Enable Mod_Rewrite

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

2.Install php 5.6

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install php5
```

3. While returning views, always use `Foldername.viewname` instead of `Foldername\viewname`
4. use `public_path()` while including files
5. `chmod -R 777` "Storage folder path"

Comment: i got blank white page when i visited somedomain.com/demo

Comment: Try checking the error logs, its most probably because of the PHP version ... Yours might be lower than 5.6

Comment: Did u try all the things that I have mentioned here??

Answer (score 0):

This file doesn't exist:

`/home/siddins/public_html/DEMO/project/app/http/helpers/backend/helpers.php`

Comment: but there is a file helpers.php in backend folder"backend/helpers.php"

Comment: you're posting a relative URL.  Post the full URL starting with /

Comment: ok,i have like this  project/app/Http/Helpers/backend/helpers.php

Comment: These folder are inside DEMO/ folder

Comment: can you help me please

Comment: The question is "What actually is this error?"  The answer is "the file does not exist", and if it is not obvious, make said file exist will solve the error.